# How to manage actionbar sherlock and support.v4 library?

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, android-support-library

I am developing an android app using **support.v4.**.

Now, I want to use CAB(Contextual Action Bar) for my list. For that I want to use **ActionBar Sherlock**.

But, when I add Library of ActionBar Sherlock, It is giving me error or conflicting support.v4 library.

So, I deleted the support.v4 library from my **lib** folder as I have read it somewhere to do so.

But now, the following code is giving exception.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

  ...

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Exception :

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
```

Answer (score 0):

ActionBarSherlock was started as a wrapper library ported to support older version of android based on the actionbar available from api level 11(not so sure which api level). After some time google officially launched the support which was not available earlier. For using actionBarSherlock make sure all your imports are from ActionBarSherlock and your activity extends SherlockActivity. Also have only one android-support-v4.jar in your build path by deleting android-support-v4.jar from other library projects. As for drawer layout I don't see anything conflicting with ActionBarSherlock except that you dont have a single android-support-v4.jar available(you need one support.jar for this to work).